# VS2022 sign in returns "Could not find a WAM account"

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to sing in with my Microsoft account (Personal) in Visual Studio 2022 17.7.3 (latest) and I get the following error message:

[image]

I can sign in using the same credentials in the same VS2022 build in another PC

I can sign with a different account (hotmail for example) in this PC

I have re-installed visual studio

I have removed the account from the system configuration and tried to sign in again

I have successfully signed in with this account in this PC in a previous VS2022 build

I have successfully signed in with this account in this PC with lastest VS2019

Any ideas what might be hapenning?

Comment: Is the PC a laptop? if so try disabling IPV6 for the wireless adapter. Having IPV6 enabled can cause signin issues for VS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Had the same problem. Go to VS Options > Environment > Accounts. Change "Add and reauthenticate accounts using:" away from "Windows authentication broker" to something else like "Embedded web browser".

This worked for me:

[image: This worked for me]

Answer (score 1):

We had some issues as well with our installation after an upgrade. This was during the authentication towards some Azure resources. The solution in our case  has been to uninstall Visual Studio completely, restart and perform a fresh install. To be clear: We did not had the WAM error, but it does affect authentication in this specific version as well

We reproduced the issue from other installations as well, where a downgrade to the previous installed version solved the issue. Also a new laptop with a fresh install was not having issues.

We were not able to pinpoint the exact root cause or cached credential that was causing issues.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because Visual Studio 2022 17.5+ can use the WAM (Web Account Manager) broker instead of the Embedded Browser, or System Web browser.  This broker is a component built into windows which handles the sign in and management of accounts.

The error message seen above is not expected and should be reported as a developer community feedback (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022) item so that the engineering teams can see the number of people encountering this issue and can ask additional questions for investigation.  Or you can upvote this feedback ticket  https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VS2022-Sign-in-Error:-We-could-not-add-/10481296

We have seen this happen for at least one user with their MSA (personal account), but it was because they had the same email address for both a MSA and WSA (work or school account).  At least in their case getting the most recent windows update fixed their issue.

Switching to either System browser or embedded browser will work around the isssue, but if possible please report the problem since we would like to fix the underlying cause.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue after selecting "System web browser", it was "Embedded web browser". the options could be changed by the latest visual studio 2022 update